# PHP Warning: 'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.10 in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

I have downloaded latest version of PHP
and I am getting error of

> PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.10 in Unknown on line 0

[image]

Comment: Which PHP version you used.?

Comment: VC15 x64 Thread Safe (2020-Feb-18 22:57:21)

Comment: If you are using ubuntu simply type ```php -v``` and check which version you have downloaded

Comment: Sir, I have written php -v on command prompt.

Comment: Not only while checking the versions of php but also while compiling/running any php file it give that 'vcruntim.dll'  14.0 is cont compatible with this php erroe.

Answer (score 2):

Download vcruntime140.dll file from https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe. Then keep it in your desktop and click right-button of your mouse and click 'Run as Administrator'. 
Make sure you have download PHP for Windows and keep it in C drive or your computer. 
Then run Visual Studio Code. 
I am sure it will work.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio Code has anything to do here.

Comment: This worked for me. Note that the page that links to the VC_redist.x64.exe specified in this post can be found here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ under "Other Tools, Frameworks, and Redistributables" - "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019"